# Project boolean value if any of the nested array item satisfies a condition in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

An example structure of my collection is below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f631d6f3792ae9ce5e35ddd"),
    "from" : "kathy",
    "content" : "hello",
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "david",
            "isfavorite" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "james",
            "isfavorite" : false
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "steve",
            "isfavorite" : true
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f631d6f3792ae9ce5e35dde"),
    "from" : "kathy",
    "content" : "hey",
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "david",
            "isfavorite" : false
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "john",
            "isfavorite" : false
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "roy",
            "isfavorite" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get messages received by a particular person. In this case if we show steve's messages I need to know if it is set as favorite by him. What I need is to project the `favorite` flag on the outer document itself if it matches some condition

I tried this but not working

```
db.getCollection('Messages_Collection').aggregate([

    {
        $match:
        {
            "to":
            {
                $elemMatch:
                {
                    "name":"steve"
                }
            }
        }
            
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            "_id":1,
            "from":1,
            "to":1,
            "isfavorite":
            {
                $cond:
                {
                    if:
                    {
                        "$to":
                        {
                            $elemMatch:
                            {
                                "isfavorite":true,
                                "name":"david"
                            }
                        },
                        then:true,
                        else:false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

**Mongo version :4.0.13**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$filter` to filter the particular person and get.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "to.name": "steve"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      isfavorite: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$to",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.name",
                  "steve"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      isfavorite: "$isfavorite.isfavorite"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BYJfIELpxzd)